# OOYALA Chromecast integration issue

Tags: android, chromecast, ooyala

I am integrating `ChromeCast` in my app which has `OOYALA`. So the problem I am facing is `OOYALA` has its own cast `SDK` and its `initialization` is done at application level where we pass our cast app id (registered on Google Cast console). As soon as I change OOYALA's sample ID and I try to `play a video an exception occurs`. Here is the `exception`:

```
com.ooyala.android.OoyalaException: cast media load failed with code 2100
    at com.ooyala.android.castsdk.CastManager$VideoCastListener.onMediaLoadResult(CastManager.java:87)
    at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager$3.onResult(VideoCastManager.java:1037)
    at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager$3.onResult(VideoCastManager.java:1032)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzly$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzly$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: You might want to check their documentation [Ooyala and Chromecast](http://help.ooyala.com/video-platform/concepts/chromecast_and_ooyala.html), this documentation provide detailed information about Ooyala and Chromecast integration. Hope this helps.